# Different elements with same XPath? How and why can it happens?

Tags: html, xpath

I realized even on one page, that two HTML elements with different CSSPathes, which are placed in fully different page areas, have the exactly same XPath. How and why can it happen? Can somebody explain it to me?

**Example**: http://goo.gl/P4oZmW

1. **First Element**: a select with default value Standard.

   ```
   <div class="list-sorting">
   <select data-current-sorting="" name="sort" id="sort">
    ...</select>
   </div>
   ```

   - **XPath**: `/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]`
   - **CSSPath**: `body > div.page > div.page-content > div.list-page-header > div.list-sorting`
2. **Second element**: a text block on the page's bottom

   ```
   <div class="list mmkcontent">...</div>
   ```

   - **XPath**: `/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]`
   - **CSSPath**: `body > div.page > div.page-content > div.right-section > div.list.mmkcontent`

I tried to get XPath and CSSPath with Chrome Dev. Tools and with Firefox+Firebug: the XPath was everywhere the same. Only Firebug with its extension gave me for the second element the CSSPath .list.mmkcontent, which i was finally able to use to accomplish my mission.

But i still don't understand, how fully different elements can have the same XPath: XPath should be the path from top of the DOM tree to the element... How can elements located on different places have the same way to them through the DOM tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> that two HTML elements with different CSSPathes, which are placed in fully different page areas, have the exactly same XPath. How and why can it happen?

Yes, this is quite easy to see. XPath is a flexible language and can select zero or more elements. CSS is also a flexible language and can select zero or more elements, but their syntax differs:

```
<p class="foo bar">
   <div>test</test>
</p>
```

Here the two different CSS selectors `.foo div` and `.bar div` will select the same element. And these different XPath expressions, `/p/div`, `/p[1]/div[1]`, `/p[div]/*[1]/../div` and `/p[@class="foo bar"]/div` all point to the same `<div>` element, but are very different.

There is a way in both CSS and in XPath to define an *exact path*. In CSS the only sure way is with `#id` syntax, assuming ids are unique, or through `nodename::nth-child[x]` syntax. The syntax `div.a > div.b` is **not guaranteed unique** with CSS.

In XPath the usual way is `/foo[x]/bar[y]` which is indisputable if `x` and `y` are numerical. Each such paths will select one unique element, or nothing.

If I look at your question, you wrote:

> ```
> /html/body/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]
> ```

and

> ```
> /html/body/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]
> ```

as being the same XPath, but they are not. Also, they do not follow the `foo[x]/bar[y]` syntax, though I may assume that there is only one `html` and one `body` element, in which case it does not matter.

The first selects `<div class="list-sorting">` on your page, the second selects `<div class="list mmkcontent">` on your page.

> But i still don't understand, how fully different elements can have the same XPath: XPath should be the path from top of the DOM tree to the element... How can elements located on different places have the same way to them through the DOM tree?

One XPath can select multiple elements, in which case you can argue that one XPath selects both. But you suggest that one XPath, that selects one element, selects another element another time, which isn't possible, unless for a bug in the XPath implementations, or when you use a dynamic page that changed between two invocations.

I didn't see that for your page. The XPaths are different, and the browsers (Chrome, Firefox) show the correct path.

When I try and select "Copy XPath" in the browsers, I get this:

```
/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]
/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]
```

Which are different XPaths.

Of course, if you used some plugin, or other means of constructing the XPath dynamically, it is entirely possible that the plugin has some bug. But the XPaths you showed are different and trying to repro your issue shows different XPaths. Perhaps it was just a slight oversight?